# Should we use honorifics when referring to monks?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

[This comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/47904/where-does-the-buddha-say-there-is-no-happiness-without-calm/47917#comment76613_47905) refers to Thanissaro Bhikkhu by name:

> Nice. And I noticed that in the updated version of Kimattha Sutta, Geoff has replaced the word "Serenity" with "Calm". Thanks.

That resulted [this comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/47917/254) from an anonymous user (who I presume is Samana Johann):

> (but how can you fools call a most Ven. by name like one of your homies...)

I habitually use the "Ven." prefix.

Should everyone always use an honorific? If I see a post or a comment which doesn't, should I edit it? Even though a moderator shouldn't usually edit comments?

I think perhaps so, to avoid causing offence.

Answer (score 1):

I feel users should respectfully use [appropriate honorifics](https://buddhistbugs.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-confusing-world-of-monastic-titles.html?m=1) such as "Venerable" together with the monastic name of the monk or nun, in the spirit of the Buddha's order to the monks in DN 16.

However, it must not be made mandatory. It should only be a strong recommendation. Moderators can also "improve" posts directly, in an indirect way to propagate this policy.

> "And, Ananda, whereas now the bhikkhus address one another as
> 'friend,' let it not be so when I am gone. The senior bhikkhus,
> Ananda, may address the junior ones by their name, their family name,
> or as 'friend'; but the junior bhikkhus should address the senior ones
> as 'venerable sir' or 'your reverence.'
> [DN 16](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html)

Comment: It happens rarely. If it is recommended though not required, isn't it easiest for everyone if we edit or 'improve' the post ourselves? And less bossy than asking the user to do it or redo it? And when it's a comment, users cannot edit it. So if the policy is that it's recommended, then I'm inclined to edit it myself without comment?

Comment: @ChrisW Yes. I agree. We can edit it directly. It's definitely more effective than telling the user to do it.